# What could this error mean?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I am having trouble with embedded linux system which keeps outputting this error:

```
libdirac_encoder.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'
```

Any idea what this error means? What is the file libdirac_encoder.so.0 for? What is it needed for?

More iformation:

The embedded linux is on an Aldebaran NAO robot - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nao_%28robot%29

And I am trying to load an example module from the documentation (genericvideomodule).

Answer (score 3):

It's a video codec library (Dirac codec), and you try to start an app that needs it and can't find it.

Without more information (what kind of system are you running, what app you try to start etc.), we can't help you any more than this.

Comment: I added more information but not sure you will be able to help. It is a very specific embedded system and as far as I know nothing needs a video codec there.

Answer (score 0):

Try runing this (assuming you can get a shell)

`ps -e |tr -s ' ' ' ' |cut -f5 -d' '|sort |uniq |xargs which |xargs ldd`

That'll show you what libraries are linked by any running userspace processes. If there's a lot of output, you can add `|grep -5i dirac` :)

If that produces nothing, then cast your net a bit wider:

`ldd /usr/bin/* /bin/* /sbin/* /usr/sbin/* /usr/local/bin/* /usr/local/sbin/* |grep -5i dirac`

It's a crude search, but it should nail down what's trying to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the libdirac package on your system. On Ubuntu Linux, you would

```
apt-get install libdirac-dev
```